# Vb2012 admin permission

Tags: vb.net

I have coded up a cleaner type of program but getting a huge error with permissions ( I think ) 
The error message is printed out like so.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6' is denied.

And it says that the error part of the code is this line

```
For Each fi In DirectroyInfos.GetFiles(filter)
```

But here is the fill block of code.

```
For Each fi In DirectroyInfos.GetFiles(filter)
            Try
                file_count = file_count + 1
                file_size = CULng(file_size + fi.Length)
                FilesToDelete.Add(fi.FullName)
            Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
                'There's really no pretty way to handle this exception
            Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
                'There's really no pretty way to handle this exception
            End Try
```

I think it's some sort of permission problem I have windows 7 and have noticed there are a lot of run has admin problems.. I think its trying to remove or gain access to a file which it does not have permission to get .

Is there anyway to fix this? Am I missing something in my coding?

Comment: And... what is your question?

Comment: well why am i getting the error and is there anyway to fix it ??

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question, you don't have write access that file.

Either skip files you don't have access to, or run the application as admin.

Comment: Is there anyway i can skip them by adding anything into the above coding ? I also run the apps has admin but get the same error...

Comment: I just tried to run the apps has admin and got the same error... Also tried the apps on xp has admin and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a limitiation with the win32 api that will skip all files in the folder if you do not have access to one of them.

Check out this solution from [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/512171/directory-enumeratedirectory-etc-unusable-due-to-frequent-unauthorizedaccessexceptions-even-runas-administrator):

[How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx)